# css not affecting div

Tags: javascript, css

I made this function to make 16 columns and rows.but I want the div that they are in to be on the right side, so for some reasons, I can't seem to change the div through (inline) css. I'm guessing its a problem with the function? Thanks for the help.

```
<html>
<body>
  <div id="buttonContainer">
    <button></button>
  </div>

  <div id="gridContainer" style = "left: 500px;">
  </div>

</body>

<script>

  const buttons = document.querySelector("#buttonContainer");

  const btn1 = document.createElement("button");
  btn1.classList.add("btn1");
  buttonContainer.appendChild(btn1);

  function divs(){
    const gridContainer = document.querySelector("#gridContainer");
    for(var i = 0; i < 17; i++){
      var row = document.createElement("div");
      row.className = "row";
      for(var x = 1; x <= 17; x++){
        var cell = document.createElement("div");
        cell.className = "gridsquare";
        cell.innerText = (i);
        row.appendChild(cell);
      }
     gridContainer.appendChild(row);
    }
  }
  divs();

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: What is `buttonContainer`? Because that's an error if that's your full code.

Comment: The idea is to put the buttons on the left and the grid on the right (havent made the buttons yet). This div will contain the buttons.

Comment: You know that your button tag is not complete? https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp

Comment: @Andy He's referencing the DOM node with id `buttonContainer` directly. It works, but it's a code smell.

Comment: @Ben Morris, thanks for catching that, but still same problem.

Comment: @Nit, I completely forgot you could do that. It's odd because the OP clearly meant to use `buttons` otherwise what's the point in creating it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to move a `div` to the right. One is to give it a `position:absolute` (so it can move around freely) and then apply `right : 0`.

I have also removed the glitchy `<button` part.

```js
const buttons = document.querySelector("#buttonContainer");

const btn1 = document.createElement("button");
btn1.classList.add("btn1");
buttonContainer.appendChild(btn1);

function divs() {
  const gridContainer = document.querySelector("#gridContainer");
  for (var i = 0; i < 17; i++) {
    var row = document.createElement("div");
    row.className = "row";
    for (var x = 1; x <= 17; x++) {
      var cell = document.createElement("div");
      cell.className = "gridsquare";
      cell.innerText = (i);
      row.appendChild(cell);
    }
    gridContainer.appendChild(row);
  }
}
divs();
```

```css
#gridContainer{
  position : absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="buttonContainer"></div>

<div id="gridContainer"></div>
```

**EDIT :** more modern/robust solution with [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

The problem with `position:absolute` is that it kind of "detaches" the element from the rest of the DOM, so other elements start placing themselves underneath it, and it can quickly cause layout nightmares.

Here's an alternative with Flexbox :

```css
.parent{
   border : blue solid 2px;
   height: 200px;
   width: 100%;
   
   display: flex;
   justify-content: flex-end;
}

.child {
   flex-basis : 150px; /* This is like width:150px */
   background : green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ohh this worked, thanks! So anytime I want to move something I have to add "absolute" to it?

Comment: Yeaaaah... not always, no. The problem with `position:absolute` is that it kind of "detaches" the element from the rest of the dom, so other elements start placing themselves underneath it, and it can quickly cause layout nightmares. I'll add another more modern and more robust solution with Flexbox <3